# Getting Distinct Values From Row Data stored in files

Tags: java

I have a .data file contains tabular data like these

Id   ZIP-code   Age    Disease

1   12377   39   Heart Disease

2   12302   32   Heart Disease

3   12378   37   Heart Disease

4   45605   53   Gastritis

5   45609   62   Heart Disease

6   45606   57   Cancer

7   78905   40   Heart Disease

8   78973   46   Cancer

9   78907   42   Cancer

and i want to get the unique / distinct values of Disease attribute and store them in an array or a list. could any one help!

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow! Please take some time to read [the help pages](http://stackoverflow.com/help), especially the sections named ["What topics can I ask about here?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and ["What types of questions should I avoid asking?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask). Also please take the [tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) and read about [how to ask good questions](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Lastly please learn how to create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: What is the field separator (like comma in csv) used here? l

Comment: yes, comma is the field separator

Answer (score 0):

PseudoCode:

```
1.Class Row (Id ZIP-code Age Disease)
2.HashMap <String,ArrayList<Row>>
3.for each line split by comma
3.a Check if column[5] exists in hashmap
    i) if Yes add Row to corresponding arraylist
    ii)if No  Create new arraylist add Row and then add to the HashMap
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you can read your data in, I would probably use the stream api to reduce the data set afterwards. See the logic inside 'function' below.

```
public class playground {

private static class Row {
    String id;
    String  zip;
    String age;
    String disease;

    public Row(String id, String zip, String age, String disease) {
        this.id = id;
        this.zip = zip;
        this.age = age;
        this.disease = disease;
    }
}


private static Set<String> function(List<Row> rows) {
    return rows.stream().map(row -> {
        return row.disease;
    }).collect(Collectors.toSet());
}

private static List<Row> readDate(String filePath) {

    ArrayList<Row> rows = new ArrayList<Row>();
    try (Stream<String> stream = Files.lines(Paths.get(filePath))) {

        stream.forEach(
                line -> {
                    String[] split = line.split(" ");
                    rows.add(new Row(split[0], split[1], split[2], split[3]));
                }
        );

    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return rows;
}

public static void main(String[] args) {

    List<Row> rows = readDate("...filepath.data");
    Set<String> unique = function(rows);
    assert(unique.size() == 2);
}
```

}

Comment: Thanks for your reply, but the records are stored in a file

Comment: Thanks, but i'm getting the errors "The type List is not generic; it cannot be parameterized with arguments <playground.Row>
 The method readDate(String) is undefined for the type playground
 Syntax error, insert "}" to complete MethodBody"

Comment: @Alex I'm not sure how your code is structured, maybe you could post that if you need more specific help. The aim of my answer was to flesh out the logic you would need to include in your own application (it wont just lift and shift); however from my current understanding of your problem, using the code contained in those two methods should get you what you are looking for.